# Prove the following limit converges using an $\epsilon / \delta $ argument

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0.0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$ this time i am reasonably sure the limit IS 0.

let $\epsilon >0 $ be given wts $\exists \delta >0 $  s.t $|\vec{x}-\vec{x_0}| < \delta \implies $ $|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2} -0 |< \epsilon$ the bottom kind of looks like delta squared? im not bad at single variable continuity but multivariable is a terribly different ball game any hints much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the limits of a multivariable function $\frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974706/finding-the-limits-of-a-multivariable-function-fracx2y2x4y2), and see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66226/multivariable-limit-proof-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-leftx-righta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|&=\dfrac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}|y|\\
&\leq|y|\\
&\leq\sqrt{|x|^{2}+|y|^{2}}\\
&<\delta\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align*}
by choosing $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: why is that less than or equal to |y|

Comment: $\dfrac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\leq 1$.