# Multivariable Limit of Rational Function $\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am struggling to show if this does or does not exist:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6}$$

I usually have no problems with limits like these. This one is throwing me through a loop because the power of $x$ is larger than the power of $y$ in the numerator, but the opposite is true in the denominator. So alot of the usual tricks for doing this kind of limit aren't working.

I tried approaching along all sorts of lines of the form $y=kx^a$ and I'm always getting that the limit is $0$. However I am struggling to prove this using the limit definition or the squeeze theorem.

The triangle inequality, $2|x||y|\leq x^2 + y^2$, and other tricks aren't working for me.

Thanks for the help.

NOTE: We have not covered polar coordinates, so the solution shouldn't have to use that.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66226/multivariable-limit-proof-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-leftx-righta) for a general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using AM-GM to show that $y^6+x^4\geq C\cdot y^2\cdot x^{\frac{8}{3}}$ by writing $x^4=\frac{1}{2}x^4+\frac{1}{2}x^4$.

Comment: Great answer (1+).

Comment: That did it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6}$$
Consider $y=kx^a; a,k\ne 0$:
$$
\frac{k^2x^{3+2a}}{x^4+k^6x^{6a}}=k^2\frac{x^{2a-1}}{1+k^6x^{6a-4}}
$$
We can check that for all: $a>\frac{2}{3},\quad \frac{2}{3}>a>\frac{1}{2},\quad \frac{1}{2}>a, \quad a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $a=\frac{2}{3}$:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}k^2\frac{x^{2a-1}}{1+k^6x^{6a-4}}=0,\quad a\in\mathbb{R}/\{0\},k\in\mathbb{R}/\{0\}
$$
which implies, that for every $C^{\infty}$ function $y(x)$ initial limit exists and equal to $0$.