# Does the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4}$ exist?

Tags: limits

I am trying to evaluate
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4}$$

I was thinking of using
$$0\leq\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4}<\frac{(x^2+y^4)\cdot y}{x^2+y^4}=y$$
which tends to as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, which means that the limit is $0$ by the squeeze theorem. Is that correct?

Comment: that doesn't sound right... for small values of $y$, $(x^2+y^4)y$ is smaller than $x^2y$

Comment: How can that be the case for the same $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multivariable limit proof: $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\left|x\right|^a\left|y\right|^b}{\left|x\right|^c + \left|y\right|^d} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66226/multivariable-limit-proof-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-leftx-righta)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4}\right|\le\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2}=|y|\xrightarrow[(x.y)\to(0,0)]{}0$$