# Calculate $ \lim_{\left(x,y\right)\to\left(0,0\right)}\frac{xy^{2}}{x^{4}+y^{2}} $

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Im trying to calculate (or prove that the limit dosent exists)

$ \lim_{\left(x,y\right)\to\left(0,0\right)}\frac{xy^{2}}{x^{4}+y^{2}} $

Wolfram says the limit does not exists, but for every path I choose the limit ends up being 0.

If someone can tell if the limit exists or not, it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try $y=x^t$ for some adequate value of $t$... or try to find this ADEQUATE value.

Comment: $\left| \frac{xy^{2}}{x^{4}+y^{2}} \right| \le \left| \frac{xy^{2}}{y^{2}} \right| = |x|$, so ...

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66226/42969 for a general result on this type of limit.

Comment: You may have miscopied this. The usual would be $\frac{x^2 y}{x^4 + y^2}  $

Comment: $$\left|\frac{xy^2}{x^4+y^2}\right|\le \frac{|x|(x^4+y^2)}{x^4+y^2}=|x|$$

Comment: @Will Jagy are we obligated to solve just the usual well known problems?

Comment: Or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297618/calculating-lim-x-y-to0-0-fracx2yx2y4, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3257954/does-the-limit-lim-x-y-to0-0-fracx2yx2y4-exist if you want the same formula

Comment: @FreeZe  you appear to be learning the methods that relate to limits at the origin in two variables. You asked earlier about when polar coordinates work, I left a comment there. If you have not already gone through it, I suggest becoming very, very comfortable with $\frac{x^2 y}{x^4 + y^2}$  As the answers here show, no change of variables is necessary in the problem you typed.

Answer (score -1):

**HINT**

By $x^2=u$ and $y=v$ we obtain

$$\left|\frac{xy^{2}}{x^{4}+y^{2}}\right|= \frac{\sqrt u v^{2}}{u^{2}+v^{2}} $$