# Multi-variable limit with polar coordinates

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

lim (x,y)→(0,0) (yx^2)/(x^4+y^2)

I don't know how to solve this multi-variable limit with polar coordinates. I tried but it gives me zero and the answer is that this limit doesn't exist.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3888013/505767) may help.

Comment: This precise question has appeared probably a dozen times on this site. You should learn to search and read what's already here before posting questions.