# Show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^4y^3}{x^2+y^4} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Show that
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^4y^3}{x^2+y^4} = 0.
\end{equation*}
Let's show this formally using an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. For $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, let $\epsilon > 0$. Then if $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $|(x,y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, then
\begin{equation*}
|y|^3\leq x^2+y^4 < \epsilon^3,
\end{equation*}
so $|y| < \sqrt[3]{\epsilon}$. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left|\frac{x^4y^3}{x^2+y^4}-0\right| &= \left|\frac{x^4y^3}{x^2+y^4}\right| \\
&= \frac{x^4|y|^3}{x^2+y^4} \\
&\leq \frac{x^4y^3}{x^4} \\
&= |y|^3 \\
&< \epsilon
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
and we are done.
Where have I gone wrong? Thanks.

Comment: squenschl. A bit of a problem: $\dfrac{x^4|y^3|}{x^2+y^4}\le \dfrac{x^4|y^3|}{x^4}$. For $x=0$, $y \not=0$ your last expression is not defined.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66226/multivariable-limit-proof-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-leftx-righta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $|x|<1$, $|y| <1$, $(x,y) \not = (0,0)$;

$x^2+y^4 \ge x^4+y^4\ge 2x^2y^2$ (AM-GM);

$|\dfrac {x^4y^3}{x^2+y^4}|\le |\dfrac {x^4y^3}{2x^2y^2}|=$

$(1/2)x^2|y| \le (x^2+y^2)\cdot 1$;

Choose $ \delta= \epsilon^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM we get $$x^2+y^4\geq 2|x|y^2$$ so we get
$$\frac{x^4y^3}{x^2+y^4}\le \frac{x^4|y|^3}{2|x|y^2}=\frac{|x|^3|y|}{2}$$ this tends to zero if $x,y$ tends to zero.

Comment: Nice alternative!

Comment: I like proofs by AM-GM!

Comment: Very nice and useful for the asker see so many different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your way is correct, more simply as $|x|<1$

$$\left|\frac{x^4y^3}{x^2+y^4}\right|\le\left|\frac{x^4y^3}{x^4+y^4}\right|=r^3\left|f(\theta)\right|\to 0$$

since $f(\theta)$ is bounded.