# Limit of given fraction approaching to zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = \frac{x^3(y^3 + \pi)}{x^2+y^2}$ is equal to zero.

My progress: I have two ideas related to this problem. Initially, I thought about using polar coordinates, but quite uncertain whether it is right approach for this problem or not. Alternatively, I am thinking about squeeze theorem: by AM-GM and triangle inequality, I managed to find a function larger than given $f$ with variables $x,y$ only. Does that imply limit of $f$ will be zero?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multivariable limit proof: $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\left|x\right|^a\left|y\right|^b}{\left|x\right|^c + \left|y\right|^d} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66226/multivariable-limit-proof-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-leftx-righta)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polar form: 
$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{x^3(y^3 + \pi)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} r\cos^3\theta( r^3\sin^3\theta+\pi)=0.  $

Answer (score 3):

Sqeeze it: $0<\left|\frac{x^3(y^3 + \pi)}{x^2+y^2}\right|< x^2y^2+x\pi.$ Take the limits now.

Comment: How about polar coordinates approach? Is that applicable in this problem?

Comment: Yes.  That is also very direct.

Comment: I did the polar method. Kindle see.