# How to prove that the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{|x|^5 + y^2}$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

At first I thought that the limit existed, but since the degree of the numerator is less than the degree of the denominator, that gives a hint as to the nonexistence of the limit. As such, the squeeze theorem cannot be applied and I have to find 2 paths where the limits give different values. I've tried many ways but they all end up giving 0.

Comment: Hint: Choose a path that approaches the origin such that the denominator collapses into one term.

Comment: @SammyBlack you fell into the trap, that proves nothing

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4141375/help-in-final-steps-showing-lim-x-y-rightarrow-0-0-frac-leftx-righta/4146090#4146090

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can bound the expression

$$0 \leq \frac{|x|y^2}{|x|^5+y^2} \leq \frac{|x|y^2}{y^2} = |x|$$

Thus the limit exists and equals $0$ by squeeze theorem.